# CakePHP Custom Query Paginator

Tags: cakephp, pagination

Currently I am got 2 page require Pagination.
I also do some research such as setting or at model do the custom Query. However the Paginator can't work.

Now I am trying add custom query paginator to index page.  (I need to use group by)
I also trying to add  custom query paginator to view page. ( I need base on the id)

**Controller:**

```
public function index() {    
    $setting =  $this->Paginator->settings = $this->Report->query('
        SELECT SUM( seats_occupied ) as totalOccupied, event_date, r.event_date_id
        FROM reports r, event_dates ed WHERE r.event_date_id = ed.event_date_id
        GROUP BY event_date
    ');

    debug($this->Paginator->paginate());
    $this->set('showDate',$setting);
}

public function view($eventDateId = null){
    if (!$eventDateId) { 
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid post'));
    }
    // We only want single post so we use FindById.
    $post = $this->Report->findAllByEventDateId($eventDateId);
    // debug($this->Paginator->paginate($post));
    if (!$post) {
        //if user requet fypcakephp/view without id will throw the not found except
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid post'));
    }

    $setting = $this->Paginator->settings = $this->Report->query("
        SELECT *
        FROM reports where event_date_id='$eventDateId' order by period asc
    ");

    //array( 'conditions' => array( 'event_date_id' => $post));

    debug($setting);
    $this->set('viewData',  $setting); //Then send this data
}
```

I also got try do at model custom Query however If I do this way , my view can't get the data I want due to I using "Group By".

```
//To custom the paginate display the thing you want. (This one return)
//public function paginate($conditions, $fields, $order, $limit, $page = 1,
//    $recursive = null, $extra = array())
//{    
//    $recursive = 0;
//
//    // Mandatory to have
//    $this->useTable = false;
//    $sql = '';
//
//   
//         $sql .= " select * from reports;";
//
//    
//
//            $sql .= " SELECT SUM( seats_occupied ) as totalOccupied, event_date,r.event_date_id
//            FROM reports r, event_dates ed WHERE r.event_date_id = ed.event_date_id
//            GROUP BY event_date; ";
//
//
//
//    // Adding LIMIT Clause
////    $sql .= (($page - 1) * $limit) . ', ' . $limit;
//
//    $results = $this->query($sql);
//
//    return $results;
//}

//public function paginateCount($conditions = null, $recursive = 0, $extra = array())
//{
//    $sql = '';
//
//    $sql .= "SELECT SUM( seats_occupied ) as totalOccupied, event_date ,r.event_date_id 
//            FROM reports r, event_dates ed WHERE r.event_date_id = ed.event_date_id
//            GROUP BY event_date";
//
//    $this->recursive = $recursive;
//
//    $results = $this->query($sql);
//
//    return count($results);
//}
```

Comment: `$this->Report->query(` - that flat out wont work, and is basically how to not use CakePHP. If you want to paginate a query with group by - first construct that query using `find()`.